# Dev Express GridView rows count

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

In `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` it is `DataGridView.Rows.Count`. But how can I get Dev Express GridView's rows count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to get the `View` inside of the `GridView` and then access the `RowCount` Property

Comment: I came here looking for a Delphi answer. If your like me you should use `yourGridNameView.ViewData.RowCount`

Answer (score 2):

In Dev Express There is a Grid Control and Inside this grid control view is there, so you can use
gridview.rowcount property to  get the number of rows in a gridview.

Answer (score 2):

`Dim rowCount As Integer = 0 '''declare rowCount as integer to hold the count value`

`GridView.RowCount = rowCount '''//Now assign the the count to rowCount`

Answer (score 0):

You can count rows using a CSS class which has applied on grid view rows for e.g.

```
var number = $('tr.dxgvDataRow').length;
```